# removing sequences from the data Pandas Python Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, slice

I have tried the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.read_csv("training.csv")
>>> data_raw = df.values
>>> data = []
>>> seq_len = 5
>>> for index in range(len(data_raw) - seq_len):
...     data.append(data_raw[index: index + seq_len])
...
>>> len(data)
1994
>>> len(data_raw)
1999
>>> del data[0]
```

The data is available here: [training.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/3ab8ee88f3fc32e78579a1054aac757d)
I have seen that the `del` removes the first element from the array. And rearrange the values like what was on 1st position, is now the 0th position, and so on.
I want to remove the values at indices: `0,4,5,9,10,14,` and so on.
But this is not getting possible with the current `del` statement as it will rearrange the values.
Please help me find the missing part.

Comment: If you don't want to change your list size, you should replace the deleted indices with a constant value, Am I right?

Comment: What is your rule of generating indices? is it `5(n-1)` and `5n - 1`?

Comment: @Chris actually that is becoming a mystery for me :P. the sequence I found a pattern was like this `0,4,5,9,10,14,15,19,20,24,25,29` and so on. I am unable to figure it out whether what formula the pattern resembles.

Comment: @JafferWilson Gotcha. I'll upload a post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. It was amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, desired removal indices: `0,4,5,9,10,14,15,19,20,24,25,29...` can be generated:

```
indices = []
for i in range(1,401):
    indices.append(5*(i-1))
    indices.append(5*i-1)
del indices[-1] # This is to remove 1999, which is out of index for df
print(indices[:12])
[0, 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, 19, 20, 24, 25, 29]
```

Then using `np.delete`:

```
data_raw = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1999, 10))
new_data = np.delete(data_raw, indices, axis=0) # Since this is not inplace op
```

Validation:

```
np.array_equal(new_data[:6],data_raw[[1,2,3,6,7,8]])
                                      # Where 0,4,5,9 is removed
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

**example code:**

```
index = [0,4,5,9,10,14]
for i, x in enumerate(index):
    index[i] -= i

print(index)


for i in index:
    del data[i]
```

Comment: No sir, what you have suggested will edit the dataframe and not the array. I want the sequence from array to get removed and not from the dataframe. Do not want to disturb original frames.

Comment: i was thinking like you first remove and the do `df.values` to get the array.

Comment: do you want to preserve the initial dataframe?

Comment: No sir. Not from the dataframes. I want the sequence from array to get removed. Do you wanna say that it will be the same then I guess you are wrong.

Comment: I do not want to copy a dataframe. as it will be safe if I operate on the arrays only and not the dataframe level

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to overcome this:

```
a = list(range(10))
remove = [0,4,5]
```

Say you want to remove the indices in `remove` from `a`. What you can do is sort the elements in `remove` in reverse order, and then remove them from `a` in a for loop as:

```
for i in sorted(remove, reverse=True):
    del a[i]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Sir is there a way I create the sequence list to be removed till the data range. Say I have 10 elements, so how I can create the `remove` list till the array range?

Comment: You mean how can you modify `remove` so that no elements are greater than the length of `a`?

Comment: Yes, sir. I mean if I need to create the array on my own, because data can be huge and need the sequence to be remove. Can you help me.

Comment: No sir, I mean `remove = [0,4,5,9]`, this should be the sequence in the remove list if the array is or `10` values. How I can create it dynamically? because imagine sir I have array of 100, how I manually can create the remove list? Please sir can you add that part in the answer it will be great.

Comment: But I don't understand what crietria you are following to create the sequence `remove`?

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that

```
a = list(range(10))

print(a)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

to_drop = [0,4,5,9] #indices to drop

values = [a[i] for i in to_drop] # values corresponding to the indices

new_v = [a.remove(v) for v in values] # new list after dropping the values
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
```

> I mean remove = [0,4,5,9], this should be the sequence in the remove
>   list if the array is or 10 values. How I can create it dynamically?

This is for 100 values of array. Generated the indices where it needs to be dropped for batch size of 10. Do correct me if I have interpreted wrongly

```
to_drop = [[j+(i*10) for j in [0,4,5,9]] for i in range(10)]
```

O/P

```
[[0, 4, 5, 9],
 [10, 14, 15, 19],
 [20, 24, 25, 29],
 [30, 34, 35, 39],
 [40, 44, 45, 49],
 [50, 54, 55, 59],
 [60, 64, 65, 69],
 [70, 74, 75, 79],
 [80, 84, 85, 89],
 [90, 94, 95, 99]]
```